# Qt5 Dll in VBA with error Run-time error 453

Tags: c++, excel, qt, vba

How I can create DLL in Qt 5 to use it in VBA? I have simple class:

**dllvba.h**

```
#ifndef DLLVBA_H
#define DLLVBA_H

#include "dllvba_global.h"

class DLLVBASHARED_EXPORT DllVBA
{

public:
    DllVBA();
    int qsum();
};

#endif // DLLVBA_H
```

**dllvba_global.h**

```
#ifndef DLLVBA_GLOBAL_H
#define DLLVBA_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(DLLVBA_LIBRARY)
#  define DLLVBASHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define DLLVBASHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // DLLVBA_GLOBAL_H
```

**dllvba.cpp**

```
#include "dllvba.h"

DllVBA::DllVBA()
{
}

int DllVBA::qsum()
{
    return 2;
}
```

In VBA I use code:

```
Declare Function DllVBA Lib "C:\QTProject\DllVBA\build-DllVBA-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\DllVBA.dll" ()  As Object

Sub test()

  Dim instance As Object

  Set instance = DllVBA()
  Debug.Print instance.qsum

End Sub
```

And result is error:

> Run-time error '453':
>
> Can't find DLL entry DllVBA in C:\QTProject\DllVBA\build-DllVBA-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Deb...

Comment: I don't know if this roadside work, can you deploy shared dll and try again. Just Qt MinGW command prompt and type DllVBA in existing directory "windeployqt.exe DllVBA.dll". and rerun your new application. Can you post a output error or successful?

Answer (score 0):

Your VBA code is expecting a function named `DllVBA` which doesn't exist in your dll (no declaration/implementation/exportation). You have just exported a native class named `DllVBA`.

Be careful, when you write below statement in VBA:

```
Dim instance As Object
```

It means you declare a COM instance reference but not a native class instance reference!
VBA is massively relying on COM objects.

In my understanding, it looks like you intend to build a COM component written in QT5 (C++) and instanciate and use it through VBA. Do you confirm?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for delay. I just want to know how I can use Qt features in VBA (or VB). There is not any example in Qt in internet. I will try learn more about COM.